# Unable to upload WatchApp build without iOS

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

As mentioned in the Apple documentation from watchOS 6.0 it is possibile to create stand alone apps.

So it is possible to upload it without the relative iOS App?

If yes, how can I do it? I'm unable to find a way.
I have a project configured to work without any iOS app (already uploaded to appstoreconnect without any error).

Comment: Yes it is. You create an "iOS" app in App Store connect but deliver a build that contains only your stand-alone watch app. Your question is a little unclear however, because you say you have already uploaded without an error. Do you have a stand alone watch app without an iOS companion app or do you have a watch app with an *optional* companion app?;  I.e. you want to be able to install it from the watch App Store without having to installl the iOS app on the iPhone.

Comment: So, it is possible to upload the Watch App without the iOS app right? I have a stand alone watch app without an iOS companion app uploaded to appstoreconnect. But I'm unable to send it to review without an iOS build... thanks in advance

Comment: Just select the iOS app in App Store connect and select the build even though it is watch only

Comment: Could you provide me a screenshot or a tutorial to do that? I'm unable to select the watch app build.. (I can't find it)

Comment: You need to ensure that the bundle id for your standalone watch app matches the bundle id in your AppStore connect app and that the version you have uploaded matches the version of the iOS app you have created in AppStore connect

Comment: Yes I'm sure of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208551/discussion-between-federico-malagoni-and-paulw11).